# Simply Modify #tag Link to Reload page with #tag in the url?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to modify the wordpress navigation items with jquery to add a onclick function where the page will reload with the #tag in the url as opposed to just going to the seciton first.

This is what i have and it does not really work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var url = jQuery('.menu-item-3614>a').attr('href');
    jQuery('.menu-item-3614>a').attr('onclick', "window.location=" + url);
    jQuery('.menu-item-3614>a').removeAttr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to just add a custom click handler that does what you want, and then cancels the action to disable navigation:

```
$(function() {
    $('.menu-item-3614 > a').click(function(evt) {
        window.location += "#tag";
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heqgb2k7/)

Comment: This didnt make the page reload only added the #tag into the url.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** (not tested yet):

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I cant use this coz i have #links in my body that i need to keep functioning, the target links are in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var url = jQuery('.menu-item-3614>a').attr('href');
   alert(url);
   jQuery('.menu-item-3614>a').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   newUrl = window.location + url;
   alert(newUrl);
   window.location.href = newUrl;
  });
});
```

Comment: This didnt cause the page to load it just did the section change in the url.

Comment: Check here its a very specific issue:

http://staging.royaldenship.flywheelsites.com/?page_id=3283
User: flywheel Pass: RDsatisphy